# How can I parse the input from a specific column into multiple columns?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have data that looks exactly like this.

[image: Raw Data]

However, the information I need is in that Message column needs to be separated into multiple columns with the data in the columns under like this.

[image: Expected result]

What would be the best way to do this?

Here is text to copy

> CorrelationId: b99fb632-78cf-4910-ab23-4f69833ed2d9 Request for API:
>   /api/acmsxdsreader/readpolicyfrompolicyassignment
>   Caller:C2F023C52E2148C9C1D040FBFAC113D463A368B1 CorrelationId:
>   b99fb632-78cf-4910-ab23-4f69833ed2d9 RequestedSchemas:
>   {urn:schema:Microsoft.Rtc.Management.Policy.Voice.2008}VoicePolicy,
>   {urn:schema:Microsoft.Rtc.Management.Policy.Voice.2008}OnlineVoiceRoutingPolicy,
>   TenantId: 7a205197-8e59-487d-b9fa-3fc1b108f1e5

Comment: Can you put some of those text strings as text in the Original Post using [edit] so we do not need to retype to test theory?

Comment: Yes I have placed it now @ScottCraner

Comment: What's the exact rule for splitting your data? (e.g. "Request for API" contains "Caller:", but it doesn't contain "CorrelationID"?) Do you also have the same labels at the same order?

Comment: This seems an exact duplicate of [What would be the most efficient way to parse the input from a specific column into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56842804/what-would-be-the-most-efficient-way-to-parse-the-input-from-a-specific-column-i) on the Stackoverflow site.  And that answer works with this data also.  What is the new problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

Find and replace `CorrelationId:` to `*`.
Repeat for `Request for API:`, `RequestedSchemas:` and `TenantId:`.
Then go to data > text to columns and choose Delimited.
For Delimiters select other and type `*`.